# WordPress Theme On Chanel Blog

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm working with a friend on the creation of a blog and they have noted that they like the minimalist approach of the Chanel blog here:

http://chanel-news.chanel.com/en/

I've looked at the source code but am still a bit unsure of how to discern a WordPress's theme through those means. Can someone help me identify the theme that was used for this blog (and if possible, how to figure this out in the future?)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Theme Name: chanel-news
Theme URI: http://www.chanel-news.com/
Description: Thème du site chanel-news.com
Version: v.1.0
Author: Sébastien Méric
Author URI: http://www.sebastien-meric.com/
```

This theme looks like it was specifically developed for Chanel, and is not available for download. Look into contacting the theme developer, or use the stylesheet as a reference here:

http://chanel-news.chanel.com/en/wp-content/themes/chanel-news/style.css

Comment: To answer your other question, every theme's main stylesheet comes with information about the theme in its comments. Wordpress reads these comments to provide information about a given theme in an administrator's dashboard. If you want access to this information in the future, use any browser inspector to find a theme's style.css file (URL contained in the <head> element in the source code)